# How to create typescript class from ajax response (or from anything)

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using Angular on frontend and make request via HttpClient. The backend returns response

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "simulatorId": 1,
        "name": "test",
        "created": "2020-04-20T12:10:19.278578",
        "isActive": false
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "simulatorId": 1,
        "name": "test",
        "created": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "isActive": false
    }
]
```

TypeScript has class

```
class SimulatorSessionViewModel {
    id: number;
    simulatorId: number;
    name: string;
    created: Date;
    isActive: boolean;
}
```

Is it possible to automaticly create class from response?

Comment: Initiate the class and assign its properties? What do you want to achive, why dont you use simple json?

Comment: For example, I have the field `created` which have type `Date` and I want to `created` field will automatically filled

Comment: Use `Object.assign`. You can otherwise use the json as is, unless you want to use methods on the class?

Comment: Yes. I want to field `created` was filled automaticlly with type `Date` and use methods of the `Date` class